# Can I deposit checks into my credit union into another bank's ATM?

Tags: united-states, fees, atm, credit-unions

My wife and I have a Bank of America savings and checking account.  We got hit with our first fee for the pleasure of having an account and I want to move to a credit union.

My wife feels comfortable making deposits via ATM, but the credit union ATM network isn't very dense where we often work and play.

How does it work if we used, for example, Bank of America's ATMs to make deposits?  She gets checks from her work more or less once a month to deposit.  What fees happen?  How long does it take to process?

Comment: Are you thinking of using BofA ATM to deposit into your credit union account? i don't think that's possible

Comment: Also why BofA is charging you? it says their checking is free if you use ATM and electronic statements.

Comment: I guess the question is can I use any old ATM to deposit.  And I think BofA made a mistake charging us, but I generally don't care for them and was looking for a reason to switch.

Comment: @MrChrister - edited title to clarify; hope that meets your approval...

Comment: @sdg - no need to ask.  Always feel free to make things better.  =)

Comment: @MrChrister - thanks.  Yeah, but I'm Canadian enough to want everybody to be happy with my version of better. :-)

Comment: @sdg - you had me at Canadian.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only make deposits into an ATM that your bank owns (or has some special relationship with).

You can make withdrawals from any ATM.

**UPDATE**: Comments show that there are some credit unions that have special relationships with other banks/credit unions and allow you to make deposits into their machines.

Comment: Our credit union is part of a network allowing us to use any credit union's ATMs.  I think this is very common for Credit Unions.

Comment: @alex do you have a link? I still believe this only let's you withdraw not deposit.

Comment: @MicheaelPryor - I do deposits as well.   Let me find a link.

Comment: http://www.cu24.com/ATMLocator/ will let you search for deposit allowing credit union ATMs.

Comment: This link is better - Specifically mentions they are a "Deposit-taking network" http://www.cu24.com/CREDIT_UNION_24/PRODUCTS_SERVICES/ATM_POS/

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative answer for your situation: many credit unions (and banks) have a mobile banking app where you can deposit checks via your smart phone by uploading a photo. Works quite well, although there is often a daily or monthly mobile deposit limit.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate possibilities would be to try to get the checks from her work direct-deposited, instead of giving her a paper check.

And another possibility would be bank-by-mail.

Comment: These are good alternatives for me, but not for my wife unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

I have used BofA and was a teller their in the past. I would strongly suggest BECU.  True free banking, you only have to maintain a $5 balance, yep 5 bucks.  You do purchase your own checks, they will even try to ensure you DO NOT overdraw your Account by moving the difference from your tied account to covert your debit/payment. With NO FEE charged to you...

I can deposit at other credit unions ATM'a if the credit union is part of the of the network.  BECU is best bank ever